# Insert value on second trigger with value from first trigger PL\SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi I try to Insert value in the second trigger with new id from first trigger only if condition is fulfiled, but I'm stuck.

`table1_trg` works

```
 CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id             NUMBER(9,0)   NOT NULL,
  subject        VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
  url_address    VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
)

 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER table1_trg
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  SELECT table1_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.id
  FROM   dual;
END;

/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER table1_url
    BEFORE INSERT ON table1
    FOR EACH ROW

WHEN (NEW.subject = 'Task')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CSB.table1 (url_address)
    VALUES ('blabla.com?' || :new.id);
END;
/
```

I insert only subject but after that i receive exception that `subject` can not be null.

```
INSERT INTO corp_tasks_spec (subject) VALUES ('Task')
```

Any ideas how to resolve it?

Comment: Do you actually want it to create a second row - so when you insert a Task record it also creates a completely separate row with that URL, using the ID from the  first? What would the URL value be for the first row, or the subject for the second row? It seems much more likely you only want to end up with a single row with both ID and URL set, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table1_SEQ
  START WITH 1
  MAXVALUE 100000
  MINVALUE 1
  NOCYCLE
  NOCACHE
  NOORDER;
```

CREATE TRIGGER

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER table1_TRG
Before Insert 
ON  table1 Referencing New As New Old As Old 
For Each Row
Declare V_Val Number; 
Begin 
        Select table1_SEQ.NextVal into V_Val From Dual;
    If Inserting Then 
        :New.id:= V_Val;
    End If; 
End;
/
```

Comment: But it's answer on first trigger which works. I don't know answer on second one.

Comment: I need add that line `IF :NEW.subject = 'Task' THEN 
     :new.url_address:= 'blabla.com?';
     END IF;
`

Comment: you have to write all thing into this trigger because if you do not this then it will show a mutation error..

Comment: This doesn't address the problem "subject can not be null"

Comment: 'If Inserting` is always true as the trigger only fires on insert. Aside from adding an extra variable to hold the sequence value, I'm not sure how this is significantly different from the OP's code? And it doesn't deal with the error being thrown by the insert in the other trigger.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be inserting a new record into the same table, you should be modifying the column values for the row you're already inserting - which the trigger is firing against. You're getting the error because of that second insert - which is *only* specifying the URL value, not the subject or ID (though the first trigger would fire again and set the ID for that new row as well - so it complains about the subject).

Having two triggers on the same firing point can be difficult in old versions of Oracle as the order they fired wasn't guaranteed - so for instance your second trigger might fire before the first, and ID hasn't been set yet. You can control the order in later versions (from 11g) with `FOLLOWS`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER table1_url
    BEFORE INSERT ON table1
    FOR EACH ROW
    FOLLOWS table1_trg

WHEN (NEW.subject = 'Task')
BEGIN
    :NEW.url_address := 'blabla.com?' || :new.id;
END;
/
```

This now fires after the first trigger, so ID is set, and assigns a value to the URL in this row rather than trying to create another row:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (subject) VALUES ('Task');

1 row inserted.

SELECT * FROM table1;

        ID SUBJECT    URL_ADDRESS         
---------- ---------- --------------------
         2 Task       blabla.com?2
```

But you don't really need two triggers here, you could do:

```
DROP TRIGGER table1_url;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER table1_trg
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.id := table1_seq.NEXTVAL; -- no need to select from dual in recent versions
  IF :NEW.subject = 'Task' THEN
    :NEW.url_address := 'blabla.com?' || :new.id;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Then that trigger generates the ID and sets the URL:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (subject) VALUES ('Task');

1 row inserted.

SELECT * FROM table1;

        ID SUBJECT    URL_ADDRESS         
---------- ---------- --------------------
         2 Task       blabla.com?2        
         3 Task       blabla.com?3
```

Of course, for anything except Task you'll have to specify the URL as part of the insert, or it will error as that is a not-null column.